# How to call Javascript function from Repeater control

Tags: javascript, c#, repeater

I know this question has already been answered but for my case none of it seems to work.

I am trying to get JS Alert when clicking the Image Button. Below is My code.

I have JS function like this:

```
<Demo:HtmlTemplates ID="HtmlTemplates1" runat="server">
        <ClientScriptTemplate>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function confirmDeleteNews() {
                    alert("Hi there");                       
                    return false;
                }

            </script>
        </ClientScriptTemplate>
    </Demo:HtmlTemplates>
```

This is my Image button inside repeater that should trigger the JS function:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterSystemNews" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterSystemNews_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>           
                <div class="news-item">                       
                    <div class="news-item-title">                      
                        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="deleteNews" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" Visible="false" OnClientClick=" confirmDeleteNews();"/>  
                </div>          
            </ItemTemplate>                    
   </asp:Repeater>
```

And this is how I bind the ImageButton in order to see it on UI:

```
protected void RepeaterSystemNews_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                //Access the button control
                ImageButton deleteNews = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("deleteNews");

                User user = _IAuthService.GetCurrentUserWithRoles();
                if (user != null && user.Roles.Any(x => x.RoleID == (int)AdminRole.Admin))
                {
                    deleteNews.Visible = true;
                    //editNews.Visible = true;                 
                }
            }
        }
```

So, When I click on Image Button, the Alert never shows up - like my JS function never get called. Is there anyone who now the solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use jQuery in your application?

Comment: @Praveen No I don't.

Comment: any error in the browser console when you click it?

Comment: Can you try moving the javascript to "head" section or at the end of "body" section

Comment: @ADyson no error, like nothing happend.

Comment: @Praveen I find the solution. When I removed <Demo:HtmlTemplates ID="HtmlTemplates1" runat="server"> inside my JS code, everything worked fine. Thx for try..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I called `<Demo:HtmlTemplates ID="HtmlTemplates1" runat="server">` inside my JS code. Once I removed that part of code, everything worked well.